# Firewall blocking SQL Server named pipes

Tags: sql-server, windows-firewall, named-pipes

If I turn off the firewall on Windows SBS 2011, I can connect to my SQL Server 2008 non-default instance by name (which I presume means it's using named pipes) without incident. After I turn it back on, I can't. I have unblocked incoming TCP and UDP ports 135, 139 and 445.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link that explains what you could do to resolve this issue

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043.aspx

Comment: Odd. The article says I should open UDP 1434. When I do that, nothing happens, but opening TCP 1434 works.

Comment: Scratch that. It looks like I'm seeing some kind of lag or caching. It stopped working a couple of minutes after I opened TCP 1434, and didn't work again until I opened UDP 1434 (and disabled TCP 1434).

Comment: It does say to open a TCP port, its on line 4 of the "To open a port in the Windows firewall for TCP access" part under the "Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 and later" Heading

Comment: Ok, well I am happy it is working for you now.

Comment: That's TCP 1433 for the default instance, and isn't relevant to named pipes, afaik.

Comment: True, that is my bad

Comment: UDP 1434 is the SQL Server Browser, which is likely telling your client to connect to the server via named pipe.